# Extracting data from Arduino MultiWii Flight Controller

Tags: serial, sensors

I am new to the world of Arduinos but have a new project going with a MultiWii Flight controller. With the MultiWii comes a software for showing all data that is measured from the sensors (acceleration, velocity, roll, pitch, etc) which is nice but I would like to have/extract this data (call raw data or something) from all sensors (i.e. the data plotting everything, in numbers). Maybe it is the simplest thing to do, and I guess I have to set up some serial connection between the controller and tell it to send this data somehow but I do not know where to start so any guidance and help is appreciated.

Comment: **1.** Do you have a link or a more detailed description of the used board / components? When searching for "MultiWii Flight controller" there are various different versions popping up.
**2.** I assume you want to data in real-time, so getting them from the software through some sort of export functionality is not an option, right?

Comment: What have you managed so far? Have you got your Arduino reading anything from the MultiWii yet?

Comment: This is the one I have: [link](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__27033__MultiWii_328P_Flight_Controller_w_FTDI_DSM2_Port.html)

Comment: And yes, data in real time is what is needed since the controller will not be connected to a computer when it is supposed to be used but to some sort of buffer (logger, memory or what to say). @PhilipAllgaier

Comment: may I ask whether have you found the solution to extracting the data from multiwii?
I am involved in a project with similar issue also.
Please assist.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're new to Arduino, I'd suggest beginning with a basic interfacing arduino activity. Once you understand reading and writing digital and analog signals it's pretty much plain sailing from there. You may want to invest some time and a bit of cash in a beginners course on Udemy (try PEter Dalmaris' course https://www.udemy.com/arduino-sbs/) it's a good start. From there, talking to the MultiWii should be a piece of cake. Also, check out http://www.multiwii.com/connecting-elements

Comment: that surely made me do some progress! @stav